# Swift: Adding UITextView in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am familiar with `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler` to add text field in `UIALertController` of `.Alert` style.

But I am trying to make a feedback form inside the alert and it needs multiple lines of text entry. I cant find a corresponding *addText**View**WithConfigurationHandler*

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Just make your own presented view controller, with a view that looks and acts like an alert view. Now it's your view, so you can put anything you want into it. https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: @matt: So there is no built-in way to do it?

Comment: Making your own presented view controller _is_ built in. A UIAlertController is just a presented view controller so there's no significant difference.

Comment: why not you add textfield itself and change border style, height & width to look like textview.

Comment: @Uttam Sinha: textField is still single line regardless of height. I need multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this. The only text input view you can natively add into a UIAlertController is a UITextField.

But then again, I would suggest presenting a feedback form that you created yourself, modally.